# I am unable to understand this iterator

Tags: loops, dictionary, iterator, iterable

Below is the code i'm trying to understand. I have read [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-iterator-tutorial)

```
my_dict = {'name': 'Klauss', 'age': 26, 'Date of birth': '15th july'}
next(v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k)
'15th july'
```

for the life of me I cant understand what v and k represent. furthermore when is k assigned a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**items()** function on a dictionnary iterate over key,value pairs of this dictionnary.

For instance, you might find this in [the documentation of a simple loop over dictionnary key/values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

So :

```
>>> [(k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items()]

[('Date of birth', '15th july'), ('age', 26), ('name', 'Klauss')]
```

Is a list containing the (key,value) pairs of the dict (in random order).

In the same way :

```
 >>> [v for k,v in my_dict.items()]
 ['15th july', 26, 'Klauss']
```

Is a list containing the values of the dict.

Finally :

```
>>> [v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k]
['15th july']
```

Is a list of the values of the dict for which the key contains the word "Date"

Note : that means, if you define :

```
>>> my_dict = {'name': 'Klauss', 'age': 26, 'Date of birth': '15th july', 'Date of death' : '16th march'}
```

You'll get :

```
>>> [v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k]
['16th march', '15th july']
```

Considering "next" meth, you may found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)
that

> next(iterator[, default])
>
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its **next**() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

Which means that

```
>>> next(v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k)
'16th march'
```

Is the first (in random order) value of the dictionnary for which the key contains the word "Date"'

Comment: is the reverse also possible? return the key instead of the value?

Comment: of course, using the same syntax, it should be :
`[k for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k]`

Comment: I may not fully understand but I feel i'm getting there. what ever is in front of "for" is what will be returned.

Comment: Exactly. For instance : `>>> [4 for k,v in my_dict.items()]
returns
[4, 4, 4, 4]`

Comment: I have been using this type of iterator for a while but mostly copy past with no idea how it was returning what I wanted. lol Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Snippet you give creates an object that is iterable from `my_dict` items in `next` function. It then prints the first value that satisfies the `if 'Date' in k` condition which is `'15th july'`.

`k, v` values are assigned when creating the iterable object (in your case it is `list`) and represents the keys (`'name'`, `'age'`, `'Date of birth'`) and values (`'Klauss'`, `26`, `'15th july'`) respectively.